# Checkboxes getting checked but no value registered because of virtual keyboard using React Native. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I have the following SearchField component in which the user can search for a task or check one of the predefined ones using a checkbox. When you focus on a SearchField it opens the virtual keyboard. When you press anywhere else the virtual keyboard is closed. The problem arrises when the user presses on a checkbox. It closes the keyboard, but because it did that the checkbox gets checked but no actual value gets registered. So when you select two tasks it only registers the last one, but both of them got checked.

What would be a good fix to this? I was thinking I could maybe disable the checkbox component when the keyboard is opened but I'm not sure on how to do this. I'd like to fix the ListItem (checkbox) component itself as this SearchField component is used multiple times throughout the app.

Edit: The ListItem components onPress method is not actually fired when the checkbox is checked while the keyboard is open.

This is the code for the SearchField:

```
<SearchField
   onConfirm={(items) => setFieldValue('task_blueprint_ids', items)}
   placeholder="Zoeken"
   selectedValues={values.task_blueprint_ids}
   items={taskBlueprintOptions}
   value={values.task_blueprint_ids}
   containerStyle={{ flex: 1, padding: 5, marginTop: 5 }}
   error={errors && errors.task_blueprint_ids}
/>
```

And this is my ListItem component:

```
interface Props<T> {
    value: boolean;
    onPress: (item: { label: string; value: T }) => void;
    item: { label: string; value: T };
}

export const ListItem = <T extends number | string>({ value, onPress, item }: Props<T>) => {
    const [keyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => {
            setKeyboardVisible(true);
        });
        const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
            setKeyboardVisible(false);
        });

        return () => {
            keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
            keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(item)} style={{ zIndex: 1 }}>
            <View style={styles.listItem}>
                <CheckBox
                    value={value}
                    boxType="square"
                    style={
                        Platform.OS === 'ios' && {
                            width: 15,
                            height: 15,
                            marginRight: 5,
                        }
                    }
                    onAnimationType="bounce"
                    offAnimationType="bounce"
                    tintColor={Colors.main}
                    onTintColor={Colors.main}
                    onCheckColor="#fff"
                    onFillColor={Colors.main}
                    tintColors={{ true: Colors.main, false: Colors.main }}
                    lineWidth={1}
                />
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{item.label}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

export default ListItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is an IOS specific issue:
https://github.com/react-native-checkbox/react-native-checkbox/issues/103

I fixed it by putting the onChange event on the Checkbox itself and the TouchableOpacity around the Text component instead of around both of them.